# finding record in look up table using linq

Tags: c#, linq, orm, telerik

I am getting to grips with LINQ and I'm stuck on the basic concepts and techniques of implementing a lookup table into objects and then querying that object (or it's association). This may be a dumb question and probably has an answer that I should have worked out myself. But I have yet to find an explanation that has made the method stick.

So I have created an example DB structure like so

[image: Example Database]

and I would like to two LINQ queries the first that gives me all of the **example2** records that are related via the lookup to a specified **object1** and the second that gives me all the **example1** records that are related to a specified **object2**

hope someone out there can kick start my brain.

something like

```
var examples = (from e in db.examples where e.example2.id == id).ToList();
```

SQL Query written quickly

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[example1] one
JOIN [dbo].[examplelookup] lu ON one.[id] = lu.[example1id]
JOIN [dbo].[example2] two ON lu.[example2id] = two.[id]
WHERE one.[id] = 1
```

Just nipped off and created this which I think should explain a bit more

[image: model]

Comment: Firstly, there are no dumb questions.  Secondly, please supply some code :)

Comment: are both example2 and example1 sharing the same key values?

Comment: Why not start with how you would ask the question to the data in a database - ignoring LINQ and just thinking SQL language, then work from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming

example1-> examplelookup relation name is examplelookups

example2-> examplelookup relation name is examplelookups

examplelookup -> example1 relation name is example1

examplelookup -> example2 relation name is example2

given `id` of example1

```
db.example1.Where(x=>x.id == id).SelectMany(x=>x.examplelookups).Select(x=>x.example2);
```

and visa versa

```
db.example2.Where(x=>x.id == id).SelectMany(x=>x.examplelookups).Select(x=>x.example1);
```

EDIT: Additional update based on Gert Arnold's suggested answer to use the any clause (this is after already accepted as an answer)

```
db.example1.Where(x=>x.examplelookups.Any(y=>y.example2.id == id));
```

and visa versa

```
db.example2.Where(x=>x.examplelookups.Any(y=>y.example1.id == id));
```

2nd Edit (again after already accepted and answer but after the question was modded to include the data model)

```
db.Example1.Where(x=>x.Id == id).SelectMany(x=>x.Example2); // could have duplicates
db.Example2.Where(x=>x.Example1.Any(y=>y.Id == id)); //alternate any form removing the duplicates
```

and visa versa

```
db.Example2.Where(x=>x.Id == id).SelectMany(x=>x.Example1); // could have duplicates
db.Example1.Where(x=>x.Example2.Any(y=>y.Id == id)); //alternate any form removing the duplicates
```

Answer (score 3):

I know you accepted an answer, but just for the record:

This is a common scenario to use `Any()`, which translates to an `exists` in sql. When you want `example1`s refering to a specific `example2` (specified by `id`) do:

```
from ex1 in example1
where ex1.example2s.Any(e => e.id = id)
select ex1
```

This gives you a distinct list of `example1` objects, whereas solutions with `SelectMany` may produce a list with duplicates.

Comment: I've incorporated the Any solution, into my answer and given you credit.  Additionally modded you up.  Strange I usually think of the any solution first, I must be having an off day today...

Comment: Thanks Gert have up scored also

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for are joins.  This code would give you all of the example1 records that have a corresponding example2 record via the join table:

```
var x = from ex1 in example1
        join exlookup in examplelookup on ex1.id equals exlookup.example1id
        join ex2 in example2 on exlookup.example2id equals ex2.id
        select ex1;
```

To get the opposite, the ex2 records, just replace `select ex1` with `select ex2`.

Comment: FYI: That code was not typed into Visual Studio so there might be an oops in there, but you should get the idea.

Comment: yes I was looking for something like this but my domain model has my lookup tables as associations and cannot now be accessed like this, (I THINK)

Answer (score 0):

Very short of time, but try starting from the lookup table so you can query both assocations

```
var examples = (from el in db.examplelookup 
                where el.example2id == id
                select el.examples1.ToList();
```

Also here no code check done.

Comment: thanks @pleun but I can't access the llokup table like this I have added an image of the model to try and illustrate what my model looks like at the moment.